# Weighted database query with randomisation

Tags: python, mysql, sql, django

I have a database model with a positive integer column named 'weight'. There's also other columns but they're not important for this problem. The weight column basically describes how 'important' this row is. The higher the value of weight, the more important. The weight will only range from 0 - 3. The default is 0 (least important).

I'd like to perform a query which selects 50 rows ordered by the weight column, but has been slightly randomised and includes rows with weights lower than what's in the results.

For example, the first 50 rows ordered by weight may all have a weight of 3 and 2. The query needs to include mostly these results, but also include some with a weight of 1 and 0. They need to be slightly randomised as well so the same query won't always return the same results. Also, even though it's limiting the results to 50, it needs to do this last, otherwise the same 50 results will be returned just in a different order.

This will be integrated in a Django project, but the DB is MySQL, so raw SQL is OK.

Performance is critical because this will happen on a landing page of a high traffic website.

Any ideas would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: could you show what you have tried so far?

Comment: it is easier to give you an answer if you provide a definitive algorithm. Now the question is a bit fuzzy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `rand()` function combined with your `weight` column

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE order by weight * rand() desc
```

Note that this means that a weight 3 can appear more probably at the beginning than a weight 2.

Weight 0 appears always at the end because 0 * any number is always 0. If you don't like that you can add 1 to weight and transform the query to

```
select * from YOUR_TABLE order by (weight + 1) * rand() desc
```

Obviously if you need only the first 50 values you can add the limit clause to the query